# Need help using Arduino R3 as serial-to-usb converter (to program something)

Tags: driver, arduino, rxtx, uart, atmega

I have researched (and learnt quite a bit), but I have little experience in programming and only really understand basic sketches so far. I would like to use the Arduino R3 (more specifically, the usb to serial converter chip) to program a full-size hobby radio.

I have connected my radio to the Arduino appropriately (5V, Rx, Tx, Gnd) and put the Arduino into Tristate mode (apparently you have to do this..), but I seem to be lacking appropriate drivers. I basically want my Arduino R3 to function exactly like this: [CP2102](http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-2-0-UART-TTL-6PIN-Connector-Module-Serial-Converter-CP2102-New-/350499583299) . Please note that I am not being super cheap. To get something like that where I live would take at the very least a month. Some people also say that I should remove the Atmega chip. The ultimate goal is that I have a device, with drivers, on a com port and not just an "unknown device".

So, my questions are: leave the Atmega on, or remove it? and which drivers do I need?

Thanks!

EDIT: I found almost exactly what I need just after I posted. For some reason I couldn't get it to work, but maybe you could help me understand? Here's the link [LINK](http://aeroquad.com/showthread.php?2587-T6-TX-Cable-alternative) If anyone is keen to help me out!

Just to make it clear: it has been done before, but I get the feeling people leave out things which they think are obvious, but to the not-yet-professional tinkerer like me aren't :/

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the links you reference are for older Arduinos with an FTDI chip. The [Arduino Uno](http://learn.adafruit.com/arduino-tips-tricks-and-techniques/arduino-uno-faq) doesn't use that. Here's a [link](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=98197.0) for using the Uno

> So! All of the older Arduinos (NG, Diecimila and Duemilanove) have
>   used an FTDI chip (the FT232RL) to convert the TTL serial from the
>   Arduino chip (Atmel ATmega). This allows for printable debugging,
>   connecting to software like PureData/Max, Processing, Python, etc.
>   etc. It also allows updating the firmware via the serial bootloader.
>
> The good news about the FT232RL has royalty-free drivers and pretty
>   much just works. The bad news is that it can -only- act as a
>   USB/Serial port. It can't act like a keyboard, mouse, disk drive, MIDI
>   device, etc.

and

> The Arduino Uno has a number of facilities for communicating with a
>   computer, another Arduino, or other microcontrollers. The ATmega328
>   provides UART TTL (5V) serial communication, which is available on
>   digital pins 0 (RX) and 1 (TX). An ATmega16U2 on the board channels
>   this serial communication over USB and appears as a virtual com port
>   to software on the computer. The '16U2 firmware uses the standard USB
>   COM drivers, and no external driver is needed. However, on Windows, a
>   [.inf file is required](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/Windows#toc4). The Arduino software includes a serial monitor
>   which allows simple textual data to be sent to and from the Arduino
>   board. The RX and TX LEDs on the board will flash when data is being
>   transmitted via the USB-to-serial chip and USB connection to the
>   computer (but not for serial communication on pins 0 and 1).

Answer (score 1):

Basically the LINK you provided, shows the user HACKING the Arduino. Using the USB/Serial(TTL) converter(what ever chip that is on your Arduino) to link to the Radio's Mini Din connector, in place of connecting to the Arduino's CPU.

As stated in other answer the Arduino uses a CHIP (of some flavor) to bridge the USB(Virtual Serial Port) to the Serial Port of the ATmega328 micro. These pins are available on the Shields connector 0(RX) and 1(TX). Hence you see the picture wiring those pins to the Radio's DIN connector.
Where I would expect in addition the RESET of the Arduino's CPU would be held to GND, this would force the pins into Hi. Simply with an extra wire jump the RESET pin to a GND.

Answer (score 0):

It's working! Somewhere along the line the drivers for my arduino seem to have been deleted, so I reinstalled them, did what you said, and learnt something.

So to clarify for others: pretty much plug and play (as the link I posted suggests), but make sure to install the arduino drivers properly.

Thanks a lot for the help!